# In AES, why do we multiply the columns by a polynomial with a repeating coefficient?

Tags: encryption, aes, symmetric

In the MixColumns step of AES, one multiplies each of the columns of the $4\times 4$ box of bytes by the polynomial $a(x)=\{03\}x^3+\{01\}x^2+\{01\}x+\{02\}$ (modulo $x^4+1$). But in this polynomial, the coefficient $\{01\}=1$ is repeated twice. Why is it acceptable for the MixColumns step of AES to have a repeated coefficient? Are there any known or conjectured attacks against AES that take advantage of this repeated coefficient? It seems like a repeated coefficient makes it easier to track how a byte propagates through the block through the rounds of encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The propagation trails of AES have been extensively analysed. As far as I recall, the repeated coefficient does not play a role. Look up Square attack, Boomerang attacks, others; You are welcome to try to discover a weakness based on the repeated coefficient.

The main impact of this MixColumns design is not repeated coefficients but the fact that the coefficients are low weight (chosen to be so for efficiency).

There are some results exploiting these properties. Some relevant papers are below:

A New Structural-Differential Property of 5-Round AES
Lorenzo Grassi, Christian Rechberger, and Sondre Rønjom [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/118.pdf)

MixColumns Coefficient Property and Security of the AES with A Secret S-Box, Abderrahmane Nitaj and Amr Youssef, AFRICACRYPT 2020 [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7334988/)

I must say that the last paper uses the low weight structure of the MixColumns matrix to mount an attack on an "AES" with secret S-box, to help recover the S-box. This is not really an important weakness, IMO.